# how to subtract a value from one column from a value from a previous row, different column in r

Tags: r, function, dataframe, apply, difference

I have a dataframe composed of 3 columns and ~2000 rows.

```
ID    DistA    DistB    
1    100    200    
2    239    390    
3    392    550    
4    700    760    
5    770    900
```

The first column (ID) is a unique identifier for each row. I'd like my script to read each row, and subtract/compare the value from column "DistA" in each row from the value of column "DistB" from the previous row. If the difference of the distance of any subsequent pairs is <40, to output that they are in the same area.
For example: In the above example comparing row 2 and 1, '239' from row 2 and '200' from row 1 is <40 and therefore in the same area. The same way 2 and 3, are in the same area ie the difference is 2 and 2<40. But rows 3 and 4 are not as the difference is 150.

I have not been able to go far, as I am stuck in the comparison (subtraction/difference) step. I have tried to write a loop to iterate in all the rows, but I keep getting errors. Should I even use a loop, or can I do this without a loop?

I am a new R learner, and this is the 'rookie' code that I have so far. Where am I going wrong. Thanks in advance:

```
#the function to compare the two columns
funct <- function(x){
    for(i in 1:(nrow(dat)))
    (as.numeric(dat$DistA[i-1])) - (as.numeric(dat$DistB[i]))}

#creating a new column 'new2' with the differences
dat$new2 <- apply(dat[,c('DistB','DistA')]),1, funct
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "dat$new2 <- apply(dat[,c('DistB','DistA')]),"
```

I'll appreciate all the comments/suggestions.

Comment: Hi, I would try copying the column B to a separate variable, shift it and then substract it in the usual way. Anyway, check the brackets when you call apply.

Comment: Try `library(dplyr) ; df %>% mutate(Dist = ifelse(abs(DistA - lag(DistB)) < 40, "Same", "Diff"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe dplyr can help you here.

```
library(dplyr)

dfData <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                     DistA = c(100, 239, 392, 700, 770), 
                     DistB = c(200, 390, 550, 760, 900))

dfData <- mutate(dfData, comparison = DistA - lag(DistB))
```

This results in...

```
dfData
  ID DistA DistB comparison
1  1   100   200         NA
2  2   239   390         39
3  3   392   550          2
4  4   700   760        150
5  5   770   900         10
```

You could then check to see if a row is within the same "area" as your previous row.

Answer (score 0):

We could also try `data.table` (similar to the approach as suggested in the comments by @David Arenburg).  `shift` is a new function introduced in the `devel` version with `type='lag'` as the default option.  It can be installed from [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table)#data.table_1.9.5
setDT(df1)[, Categ := c('Diff', 'Same')[
             (abs(DistA-shift(DistB)) < 40 )+1L]][]
 #   ID DistA DistB Categ
 #1:  1   100   200   NA
 #2:  2   239   390 Same
 #3:  3   392   550 Same
 #4:  4   700   760 Diff
 #5:  5   770   900 Same
```

If we need both the 'difference' and 'category' columns

```
setDT(df1)[,c('Dist', 'Categ'):={tmp= abs(DistA-shift(DistB))
               list(tmp, c('Diff', 'Same')[(tmp <40)+1L])}]
 df1
 #   ID DistA DistB Dist Categ
 #1:  1   100   200   NA    NA
 #2:  2   239   390   39  Same
 #3:  3   392   550    2  Same
 #4:  4   700   760  150  Diff
 #5:  5   770   900   10  Same
```